# Show the times of a tag being tagged to a specific object using acts-as-taggable-on in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags, acts-as-taggable-on

Sorry for such a long topic, that what I can only express with these words.

For example：
`@article=Article.new`

and users could tag `@article` differently, with their own tag( like `good`)

Then, how can I show the `good` tag how many times being taged to the **@article**?

> > After searching around, I just find solutions to count the **overall** times a tag being tagged( In this case, how many times the 'good' being used on Article.all), like :[Acts-as-taggable-on find all tags by context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595112/acts-as-taggable-on-find-all-tags-by-context). Just like what we have in stackoverflow's tag feature

Answer (score 0):

Use `Article.tagged_with('good').count`

Comment: But how does it associate with @article?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using the corret meaning of 'object', maby I shoud use 'instance' instead?