# Rails: efficient way to collect data of one model from another with many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I have two models, Bookmark and Tag. The tags are implemented by acts-as-taggable-on gem, but I will explain the main point here.

Bookmark model contains an *url* field. Given a Bookmark instance @bookmark, @bookmart.tags returns its tags. Different bookmarks can share a same tag (that is the *many* part from Tag).

Tag has name, and taggings_count. The taggings_count field stores how many bookmarks to which the tag are tagged. Behind the scene, there is an taggings table, but that doesn't matter.

Now is the question, I want to retrieve all those tags that are tagged by bookmarks with specific url value, and the result should be sorted by the number of bookmarks to which a certain tag is tagged (that number is not the same as the taggings_count field, which represents tagging count for all bookmark, but want bookmark for a specific url here). How can it be done so that the generated sql is efficient?

I know I can write directly in sql for efficiency, but I am also wondering whether Rails can do the same without hurting too much performance, so that I don't have to inject sql code in my Rails application

Following is the table definitions, in the taggings table, taggable_id acts as a foreign key to Bookmark, and tag_id a foreign key to Tag:

```
CREATE TABLE `bookmarks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text,
  `private` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `list_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `taggings` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taggable_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taggable_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tagger_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tagger_type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `context` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `taggings_idx` (`tag_id`,`taggable_id`,`taggable_type`,`context`,`tagger_id`,`tagger_type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taggings_count` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_tags_on_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: if you're concerned with the efficiency of the SQL query, you should give us: the indexes on the 3 tables, the columns of the "taggings" table.

Comment: Also, which Rails version are you using? which DB?

Comment: @tompave Check my updates for the table definitions. I am working on Rails 4.1.0, and it will be deployed to a server with mysql

Comment: are you using active record from rails?  or another DB interface.

It would seem you just need the id of the bookmark you care about. 

bookmark.where(url:your url).pluck(:id)[0] if there's just one.  then just do a tabable.where(id:) and grab the tag urls.

Comment: @bobbdelsol Yes, I am using active record. And there could be multiple   bookmarks with same url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be simple, [acts-as-taggable-on](http://rubydoc.info/gems/acts-as-taggable-on/3.2.4/frames) can actually operates on an association. The docs have that sample, I just didn't noticed:

```
Bookmark.where(url: url).tag_counts_on(:tags).sort_by(&:taggings_count).reverse.map(&:name)
```

The only problem is that, the result is stilled sorted by popularity of those tags, no matter in what kinds of context they are popular. That doesn't really matter, though. The point is this rails statement only generates a single sql:

```
SELECT tags.*, taggings.tags_count AS count FROM "tags" JOIN (SELECT taggings.tag_id, COUNT(taggings.tag_id) AS tags_count FROM "taggings" INNER JOIN bookmarks ON bookmarks.id = taggings.taggable_id WHERE (taggings.taggable_type = 'Bookmark' AND taggings.context = 'tags') AND (taggings.taggable_id IN(SELECT bookmarks.id FROM "bookmarks"  WHERE "bookmarks"."url" = 'http://kindleren.com/forum.php?gid=49')) GROUP BY taggings.tag_id HAVING COUNT(taggings.tag_id) > 0) AS taggings ON taggings.tag_id = tags.id
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution:

```
bookmark_ids  = Bookmark.where(url: "http://foobar.com").pluck(:id)
taggings      = Tagging.where(taggable_id: bookmark_ids).where(taggable_type: "Bookmark")
tag_ids       = taggings.pluck(:tag_id).uniq
tags          = Tag.where(id: tag_ids).order(taggings_count: :desc)
```

It theory it could be written using the `joins()` method from ActiveRecord, but I don't know how the gem you're using defines the associations.
This might or might not work:

```
Tag.order(taggings_count: :desc)
   .joins(taggings: :bookmark)
   .where(bookmark: { url: "http://foobar.com" })
```

You could also write raw SQL, but it feels dirty in rails.

Comment: Thanks, tompave. There is one thing that you have missed in my question, that the result should be ordered by something other than taggings_count field in this design. But your answer push me to learning more about [acts-as-taggable-on](http://rubydoc.info/gems/acts-as-taggable-on/3.2.4/frames). I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595112/acts-as-taggable-on-find-all-tags-by-context) and think that maybe I can redesign it and make the url as context. Then I can use Bookmark.tag_counts_on('certain url') to get tags for a url. In the new design, taggings_count can be used.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I missed that. If the associations are in place, you can look at the methods [`includes` and `references`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes)

Comment: I compared your first solution with the one I posted, the generated sql turns out to be similar, the gem one is just more compact, in ruby and sql. I edited your code to inlude context as a condition, and combine the second and third statement, not sure whether writing them as two would cause two statements instead of one being executed. BTW, the joins couldn't work, I don't know whether there is a way to configure rails about how to join tables.

Comment: Ok, but you should never edit another person's answer in this way. Even if an answer is not correct, you should __not__ correct it. The meaning of my answer is lost, and I would __not__ write code in this way: I don't know enough of the library to reference the namespaces as you've done, and I would not chain method calls in such a fashion. the purpose of the _question and set of answers_ model is that you should either choose the right answer, or provide one yourself. Wrong answers can be ignored or downvoted.

Comment: I reverted the changes. If you are unhappy with my answer you can downvote it and choose another one as winner.